# Every time I restart my computer, Windows XP forgets my folder settings

Tags: windows-xp

This started a couple of weeks ago. I always view my folders sorted with most recently modified file on top, but now every time I restart my computer it resets every folder to be alphabetically sorted. It's more annoying than I expected - how can I fix this?

Comment: Try the following: View any folder in Explorer and set it up the way you want, then select "Folder Options..." from the Tools menu and pick the View tab. At the top of section there should be an "Apply to All Folders" button. Click it and confirm you want to perform the operation.

Answer (score 0):

The registry settings probably just got messed up as it is occasionally wont to do. Try deleting them and restarting Windows:

1. Save all files and exit all programs
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the *Task Manager*
3. Switch to the *Processes* tab
4. Click the *Image Name* header to sort by process name
5. Find all instances of `explorer.exe` and kill them (click the item, then `[End Process]` or <kbd>Del</kbd>)
6. Open the registry-editor (*File → New Task*)
7. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows`
8. Expand the `Shell` branch
9. Delete (<kbd>Del</kbd>) the `Bags` sub-branch (or just rename it to something like `Bags-` for now with <kbd>F2</kbd>)
10. Repeat step 9 for the `ShellNoRoam` branch
11. Close the registry-edtior
12. Restart Explorer (*File → New Task*, `explorer`)